# Corrupt weird files in Android Folder of SD Card after data transfer to PC

Tags: data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I had a 32GB microSD card and I transferred a few files to my computer using the SD card reader, but when I inserted it in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 SMT230_NU a separate folder named "Drive" was created with all my folders, all files were working fine except that the Android folder, instead of containing the data and obb folders, contained files without any format, the folder is still taking as much space as it took before but I cannot access anything
[image][image]
All my downloads were very important and they were in the Android folder, is there any way to recover my files?

Comment: two possible reasons: folder is encrypted, or file system is corrupt. it's not recommended to use this folder anyway. there is a Download folder by default

Comment: This has happened to me before in two different scenarios. 1: Cheap µSD cardreader corrupted the card. 2: Virus. Recovery anything you can from the card ([See my tutorial here](https://superuser.com/a/1347139/926024)) and completely re-format it (preferably wiping it clean first). Run a few tests to see if it still works properly and if not, replace it. Scenario 1 damaged my card permanently, scenario 2 it was able to recover from.